# How import magento1.7 product with custom option?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In my magento1.7 store have large number of products with custom option. How to import a product with custom option?

My products are all simple products.

Suggest me to save my time.

Thanks,

Shivaji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) for mass import of products

Comment: My products are all a simple products. So we can;t use magmi for import

Comment: yes you can. according Magmi features Can import configurables , simples , grouped